# Adding to a datetime

Tags: powershell, datetime

Forgive me if it's already been asked here somewhere, but I couldn't find it, but here goes.

In a log file I have, there's a time at which the values were logged and the time is written in `HH:mm:ss`.

I need to parse multiple rows of that file, and so far the only way I can do that it adds a few minutes to the specific time I want to start parsing rows from.

This is the code I currently use to add. However, when the Minute is something like "05" or anything below 10, it just removes the 0 and I end up having a time like this: 15:7:49 while it should be 15:07:49.

When it DOES work and the time doesn't exist in the file, it adds another second. Sometimes the logtool skips a second, but never more than 1.

```
$a = [datetime]::ParseExact($a,"HH:mm:ss",$null)
$time = [string]$a.Hour + ":" + ($a.Minute+5) + ":" + $a.Second
if ($time -eq $time){$time = [string]$a.Hour + ":" + ($a.Minute+5) + ":" + $a.Second}
else {$time = [string]$a.Hour + ":" + ($a.Minute+5) + ":" + ($a.Second+1)}
```

Basically, what I'm asking is, how can I add any number to the minute or second, without losing the `HH:mm:ss` format?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `$a` variable is a datetime so you can just use `AddHours`, `AddMinutes`, `AddSeconds` on it. Example `$a.AddHours(1)`

Comment: and you should postpone converting back to a string as long as possible. The only decent reason to convert back to a string is for display purposes *(that includes logging)*.

Comment: this `if ($time -eq $time)` will always evaluate to true btw.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that part when I tried another way to script this. Thank you for pointing it out nonetheless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) objects have methods to add seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc.

```
$a.AddMinutes(5)
```

The same methods can be used to subtract time from a timestamp by adding a negative value:

```
$a.AddMinutes(-5)
```

The output format can be defined e.g. via the `ToString()` method or the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
$a.ToString('HH:mm:ss')
'{0:HH:mm:ss}' -f $a
```

However, as Lieven Keersmakers [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481962/adding-to-a-datetime/45482262#comment77924725_45481962), converting a `DateTime` value back to a formatted string should be reserved for displaying the value to a user (messages, logging, reports, etc.). In your script `DateTime` objects are far easier to work with than strings, so you should stick with them as long as possible.

Comment: Using this and some more info on the adding, I got it working properly now. Thank you all for the quick replies!